# Saving partitioned parquet on AzureML

Tags: azure-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm working at a company that only allows us to use AzureMl.

The output for one of our models is data enrichment: we read a table with customer information, segment it and then return a pandas DataFrame with `customer_id`, `segment_name`, `segment_type`, `reference_dt` and `processed_dt`.

I wanted to save this information as parquet files, at the Azure blob storage, with `reference_dt` as partition.

I can't find in the Docs how to do this. What I did find was the `Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe` that stores the data in a non-customizable path, with an un-human-readable UIUD as the folder name.

Whenever we update that segmentation, that method creates another version of the dataset, whose file path is under a different UIUD.

Is there a way for me to have control on where the data will be stored so that I can later safely automate this procedure?

Answer (score 2):

I finally discovered, buried deep inside the AzureML docs, that the Datastore resource has an upload parameter, so I can completely bypass the Azure ML's Datasets.

My solution became something like this:

```py
# Export to local file system
temp_file_dir = "dir_path"
target_path = "target_dir"

# Force PyArrow to create files using the same file name
# Otherwise, the filename will consist of a different uuid everytime and,
# not overwritten at the file storage.
filename_callable = lambda x: "data.parquet"

# To use `partition_filename_cb` the engine must be `pyarrow`
df.to_parquet(
    temp_file_dir,
    engine="pyarrow",
    partition_cols=["reference_dt"],
    partition_filename_cb=filename_callable,
    index=False,
)
# Upload to storage
datastore = Datastore.get(ws, datastore_name)  # ws is the AzureML workspace
datastore.upload(
    src_dir=temp_file_dir,
    target_path=target_path,
    overwrite=True,
)
        
# Clean temporary files
shutil.rmtree(temp_file_dir)
```