# Path import parquet in AzureMachineLearningFileSystem

Tags: dataframe, azure, machine-learning, save, parquet

I have a problem with.... AzureMachineLearningFileSystem ;)
I use article from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-data-interactive?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=adls
And.. i dont know how i can save file parquet in location.

I tried

```
F_AUDIT.to_parquet("azureml://subscriptions/xyz/resourcegroups/xyzz/workspaces/xyz/datastores/xyz/paths/2_FILES_PIPE/SPACE_DEF/text.parquet", 
                   engine = 'pyarrow', 
                   compression = 'gzip')
```

But i have a error

> Message: rslex failed, falling back to clex.
> Error Message: ScriptExecutionException was caused by StreamAccessException.
> StreamAccessException was caused by NotFoundException.
> Found no resources for the input provided

What are the ways?
PS. i know i can use

```
F_AUDIT.to_parquet("SPACE_DEF/text.parquet", 
                   engine = 'pyarrow', 
                   compression = 'gzip')
```

or upload
[Saving partitioned parquet on AzureML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712598/saving-partitioned-parquet-on-azureml)

But i want specific location in storage (specific blob containers/data stores, when i save like above, file is saving in File Shares... no Blob Containers)

Answer (score 1):

You use below code for uploading parquet files to datastore.

First, get the **datastore** object for the workspace.

```
from  azureml.core  import  Workspace, Datastore
ws = Workspace.from_config()
datastore_name = 'workspaceblobstore'
datastore = Datastore.get(ws, datastore_name)
```

Here, give datastore name linked with the blob container.
After, getting this create the local directory if not exists.

```
dir = "SPACE_DEF"
file_name="text.parquet"
file_path = os.path.join(dir,file_name)
print(file_path)
if  not  os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir)
```

[image]

Below is my data frame.

[image]

Then, write data locally and upload it to datastore container.

```
df.to_parquet(file_path,
    engine = 'pyarrow',
    compression = 'gzip')
```

Writing data locally.

[image]

Upload it to datastore.

```
datastore.upload(src_dir=dir,target_path=dir)
```

[image]

Output in container

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer JayashankarGs - i saw your solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712598/saving-partitioned-parquet-on-azureml (i wrote about this link). I thought there was a simpler way by specifying the path (like read csv with path.... with azureml://) , not uploading, because uploading probably costs money.

Comment: Yes. I tried that way. But at the end you need to create a directory in container. If you create then we can give directly the path.

Comment: So you suggest me, we can save a parquet to datastore? How ? Link with azureml no working...